# Silverlight Polygon - click within?

Tags: silverlight

I have a Polygon (a Hex for a board game) in Silverlight, something like;

```
public class GridHex : IGridShape
{
    .....
    public IList<Point> Points { get; protected set; }
    public bool Intersects(Point point) { ... }
}
```

I would like to be able to say

```
if(myHex.Intersects(clickedPoint)) { ... }
```

However I'm unsure of which algorithm to use within the Intersects method - currently I'm using an internal "bounding box" inside each Hexagon to detect if a point is within it, but there must be an algorithm to figure this out? I know the coordinates for the 6 points of each Hexagon.

I was thinking I could maybe create a Silverlight Polygon and do some kind of hit testing? Of course this would be rather memory intensive (I'd be iterating a large number of Hexes to see which Hex a mouse click falls within...) so it might be better to use a mathematical formula to work out if a point is within a Hex....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) nicely explains an algorithm for finding out if a point is inside a polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into native support using the [FindElementsInHostCoordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838402(VS.95).aspx)? I'd expect this to be faster since it probably utilizes unmanaged code.

Here's a [sample](http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Default.aspx?tabid=67&EntryID=95) which works with vector shapes, supported in Silverlight 2.

And here's [an updated sample](http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/160/Default.aspx) which utilizes a WriteableBitmap to extend support for hit testing to bitmap images, as well.